# @RequestBody vs HandlerMethodArgumentResolver in Spring

Tags: spring

I have two solutions for the same problem but I'm not sure which solution is better to use in the long run.

## solution 1:

The controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/skill/leatherworking/curing/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response startCuring(final UserEntity userEntity, @RequestBody @Valid final CuringCreateRequest curingCreateRequest) {
    final CuringResult result = curingService.cure(userEntity, recipeDefinitionCache.getDefinition(curingCreateRequest.getRecipeId()));
    ...
}
```

And the domain object is:

```
public class CuringCreateRequest {

    @Min(1)
    private int recipeId;

    ...
}
```

## solution 2:

The controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/skill/leatherworking/curing/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response startCuring(final UserEntity userEntity, @Valid final CuringCreateRequest curingCreateRequest) {
    final CuringResult result = curingService.cure(userEntity, curingCreateRequest.getRecipe());
    ...
}
```

Here we also have a HandlerMethodArgumentResolver:

```
public class RequestContextHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(CuringCreateRequest.class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(final MethodParameter parameter, final ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, final NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        final WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        ... //Manually resolve the argument via JsonMapper and RecipeDefinitionCache. This way we can create an immutable class and that's a bonus too.
    }
}
```

And the domain object is:

```
public class CuringCreateRequest {

    @NotNull
    private RecipeDefinition recipe;

    ...
}
```

Which solution is better to use in the long term? Especially in a medium or big project? I prefer the **solution 2** because its cleaner and the controller have less responsability but not exactly sure that it's adventages are good enough for the hassle of creating another class for every different parameter. Especially where a @RequestBody can solve the problem under 2 seconds.

Comment: And why wouldn't you be able to create a immutable object with solution 1. Use direct field access instead of property access and presto. You don't want to roll your own implementations for each and every class you need to bind, use the framework to your advantage.

Comment: @M.Deinum The main thing why I would use HandlerMethodArgumentResolver because I can resolve the recipe in the resolver and not in the controller. This way the controller shouldn't even know about recipeDefinitionCache. (I try to avoid the controller as much as possible usually.)

Comment: Use a custom (De)Serializer from Jackson (assuming you use that) to apply that functionality. Also why should the controller know, you can always move that line to the service (where it should be in the first place imho) to do the lookup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend going with option 2. One way that you can enhance this is to add programmatic validation methods in the setter methods of your object, and call the setter methods in your implemented HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

e.g. something like

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar;
    ...
    public void setBar (String bar) {
        //disallow special characters
        if ( !StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(bar)
            this.bar = null;
        else
            this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

And then in your custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver use said setters:

```
public class CustomFooHandlerMethodArgumentResolver extends HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
   @Override
   public boolean supportsParameter (MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(Foo.class);
    }

   @Override
   public Object resolveArgument (MethodParameter methodParam, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {

        Foo myFoo = new Foo();
        myFoo.setBar(webRequest.getParameter("bar"));
        ...
        return myFoo;
    }
}
```

With this kind of implementation you only need one central point of validation (the setter methods) and you prevent illegal values in the fields from being set both at the endpoint and throughout the program.

The other thought would be that you can add far more complex validation logic in the setter than you can with annotations, including making additional method calls to handle disallowed values (or additional method calls to get default values, etc)

Bottom line, no right way, depends on the scope of the project, but you can be probably as rigorous as you need to with the option 2, whereas you're slightly limited (but up and running faster) with option 1.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same idea.